# SQL Azure - One session locking entire DB for Update and Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

SQL Azure issue.

I've got an issue that manifests as the following exception on our (asp.net) site:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
> the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been
> terminated.

It also results in update and insert statements never completing in SMSS. There aren't any X or IX locks present when querying: `sys.dm_tran_locks` and there are no transactions when querying `sys.dm_tran_active_transactions` or `sys.dm_tran_database_transactions`.

The problem is present for every table in the database but other databases on the same instance don't cause the problem. The duration of the issue can be anywhere from 2 minutes to 2 hours and doesn't happen at any specific times of day.

The database is not full.

At one point this issue didn't resolve itself but I was able to resolve the issue by querying `sys.dm_exec_connections` finding the longest running session, and then killing it. The odd thing is, that the connection was 15 minutes old, but the lock issue had been present for over 3 hours.

Is there anything else I can check?

**EDIT**

As per Paul's answer below. I'd actually tracked down the problem before he answered. I will post the steps I used to figure this out below, in case they help anyone else.

The following queries were run when a "timeout period" was present.

```
select *  from sys.dm_exec_requests
```

[image: Request Stats]

As we can see, all the WAIT requests are waiting on session 1021 which is the replication request! The `TM Request` indicates a DTC transaction and we don't use distributed transactions. You can also see the wait_type of `SE_REPL_COMMIT_ACK` which again implicates replication.

```
select * from  sys.dm_tran_locks
```

[image]

Again waiting on session 1021

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_wait_stats ORDER BY wait_time_ms desc
```

[image]

And yes, `SE_REPL_CATCHUP_THROTTLE` has a total wait time of 8094034
ms, that is 134.9minutes!!!

Also see the following forum for details on this issue.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/c3003a28-8beb-4860-85b2-03cf6d0312a8

> I've been given the following answer in my communication with
> Microsoft (we've seen this issue with 4 of our 15 databases in the EU
> data center):
>
> Question: Have there been changes to these soft
> throttling limits in the last three weeks ie since my problems
> started?
>
> Answer: No, there has not.
>
> Question: Are there ways we can
> prevent or be warned we are approaching a limit?
>
> Answer: No. The issue
> may not be caused by your application but can be caused by other
> tenants relying on the same physical hardware. In other words, your
> application can have very little load and still run into the problem.
> In other words, your own traffic may be a cause of this problem, but
> it can just as well be caused by other tenants relying on the same
> physical hardware. There's no way to know beforehand that the issue
> will soon occur - it can occur at any time without warning. The SQL
> Azure operations team does not monitor this type of error, so they
> won't automatically try to solve the problem for you. So if you run
> into it you have two opitions:
>
> 1. Create a copy of your db and use that and hope the db is placed on another server with less load.
> 2. Contact Windows Azure Support and inform the about the problem and let them do Option 1 for you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be running into the SE_REPL* issues that are currently plaguing a lot of folks using Sql Azure (my company included).

When you experience the timeouts, try checking your wait requests for wait types of:

- SE_REPL_SLOW_SECONDARY_THROTTLE
- SE_REPL_COMMIT_ACK

Run the following to check your wait types on current connections:

```
SELECT TOP 10 r.session_id, r.plan_handle,
r.sql_handle, r.request_id,
r.start_time, r.status,
r.command, r.database_id,
r.user_id, r.wait_type,
r.wait_time, r.last_wait_type,
r.wait_resource, r.total_elapsed_time,
r.cpu_time, r.transaction_isolation_level,
r.row_count
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
```

You can also check a history of sorts for this by running:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_wait_stats
ORDER BY wait_time_ms desc
```

If you're seeing a lot of SE_REPL* wait types and these are staying set on your connections for any length of time, then basically you're screwed.
Microsoft are aware of the problem, but I've had a support ticket open for a week with them now and they're still working on it apparently.

The SE_REPL* waits happen when the Sql Azure replication slaves fall behind.
Basically the whole db suspends queries while replication catches up :/

So essentially the aspect that makes Sql Azure highly available is causing databases to become randomly unavailable.
I'd laugh at the irony if it wasn't killing us.

Have a look at this thread for details:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/c3003a28-8beb-4860-85b2-03cf6d0312a8

Comment: Thanks a million Paul, you just confirmed the conclusion I can to! I'll update my post with the data I got out of it in case it helps others diagnose. I have also opened a support issue with MS about this. We're a gold partner, for all that counts, so hopefully we'll get an answer sometime before Christmas!

Comment: No worries, sorry to hear you're having the same issues as we are. It's a serious problem and pretty much impossible to mitigate from a coding perspective.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this Paul, I've been encountering the same issues and have been hunting everywhere for a reasonable answer.  This was my suspicion and your queries helped confirm it.

Comment: No worries, bummer you're suffering this too. I think this problem is a lot more widespread than MS is letting on.  My support ticket is still open and the dude I'm dealing with is frankly an idiot.  I learned more about the problem from googling than I have from my support guy.  
Things have improved for us somewhat, which is good since it's buying us time to figure out whether or not to do a (painful, costly) migration to Amazon RDS.  
Pity MS doesn't offer Sql Azure in a reserved instance capacity :/

Comment: Paul, we have had the same experience as you.  Although since Amazon RDS doesn't offer Multi-AZ deployments for SQL Server we're concerned Amazon's reliability might not be much better than Sql Azure so are looking at Rackspace and GoGrid.

Comment: This issue still persists well into 2014. In my case, MS Support has been slow to acknowledge the issue even with diagnostic reports that very clearly show every update waiting on `SE_REPL_SLOW_SECONDARY_THROTTLE`. I've had to move the affected database off of SQL Azure.